# how to selected data based on condition null or not null mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-select-db

i have table called my_table like this

```
+------------+-------+-------+
|  product   | type1 | type2 |
+------------+-------+-------+
| Banana     | NULL  | A1    |
| Grape      | NULL  | B1    |
| Watermelon | A     | A1    |
| Orange     | B     | A1    |
+------------+-------+-------+
```

i want to select product based on his type, if type1 NULL then the type using type 2, if not then use type 1

so the expected results like this

```
+------------+------+
|  product   | type |
+------------+------+
| Banana     | A1   |
| Grape      | B1   |
| Watermelon | A    |
| Orange     | B    |
+------------+------+
```

Comment: Show us any attempted query from your testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
    product,
    COALESCE(type1, type2) AS type
FROM yourTable;
```

The `COALESCE(a, b)` function will return `a`, should it be not `NULL`, otherwise it would fallback to returning `b`.

Comment: i want to ask sir, if type 1 and type 2 comes from tbl1 (for type1) and tbl2 (for type2) is it true i wrote SELECT
    product,
    COALESCE(tbl1.type1, tbl2.type2) AS type
FROM yourTable, tbl1, tbl2; ?

Comment: @FachryDzaky Yes, that looks correct and valid to me.